# NodeJS Promises hangs on res.send(data)

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise, multer

I'm working on a NodeJS server and performing some file parsing and sending back the result to an AngularJS client. I have the router call below:

```
router.post('/parseFile', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {                                          
let response = response_template                                                                               
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {                                                          
    commands.parseFile(req.file.filename,                                                    
                       req.file.originalname,                                                
                       resolve,                                                              
                       reject);                                                              
})                                                                                                             
    .then(function(result) {                                                                                   
        console.log("This is working", result);                                                                
        res.status(200);                                                                                       
        res.send(data);                                                                                        
        console.log("Should be here...?");                                                                     
    }, function(error) {                                                                                       
        console.log("There was an error", error);                                                              
        res.status(400);                                                                                       
        res.send(data);                                                                           
    });
```

});

The log statements do say **"This is working"** and prints out the result too. However, it does not print out the **"Should be here...?"** statement after the res.send(data).

The data is also never sent and the client says no response was received. I've looked through the Promise documentation but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is not defined. That part of your code is throwing and the exception is being swallowed. Perhaps you mean to use `result`?

Comment: OH MY GOD. -Insert expletives- Thank you so much for your help. I didn't see any error message on the client or server. Are there any tools one can use well with promises?

Comment: Well, you could insert a `debugger` statement in the `then` handler and use node-inspector to step through.

Comment: Right but I mean I thought that sending back null would be improperly formatted JSON and that should register an error on the client but nothing showed up.

Comment: Long ago and far away, Javascript engines would see an undefined variable and just pass around `undefined`. Yae, there was much gnashing of teeth as developers tried to track down typos in their variable names. In came `'use strict'` which required that variables be declared before being used -- and that's become default behaviour on node. Try open node at the console and type `console.log(data);` -- you get an exception, not the value `undefined` logged to the console